# Null Pointer Exception for Ebean Insert Query

Tags: java, playframework, nullpointerexception, ebean

I have E bean model of my table Countries and Indicators.
The indicators model looks like this

```
public class Indicators extends Model {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
public Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "indicator")
public HashSet<Indicators> transactions;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "countryid")
public Countries country;
}
```

and My countries model Looks like this

```
    public class Countries extends Model {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

           @Id
          @Column(name = "COUNTRYID")
          public Long countryId;

          @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
          public HashSet<Countries> indicators;
             }
```

and I am trying to call the insert function

```
  private static void procM007_SP003(ExcelInd excelRow, String indicator_code) {

    // Insert
    Indicators indObj = new Indicators();
    indObj.country.countryId=542L;
            indObj.save();
```

however, the **indObj.country.countryId** causes null pointer exception.

Any help is appreciated.  thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default instance variables are set to `null` and as you have not initialized `country` variable of object `Indicators`, so it will be null. And hence setting `countryId` on null object will lead to `NullPointerException`.

You need to initialize country attribute of Indicators object also:

```
Indicators indObj = new Indicators();
indObj.country = new Countries();
indObj.country.countryId = 542L;
indObj.save();
```